# Update Firestore with user last active date

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm looking at writing the date a user was last active to my firestore users table.  This information is available in the metadata of the user - lastRefreshTime.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserMetadata

Has anyone already done this before?
I am looking for an efficient way to do this with minimal writes.
I could run a daily process that checks all users and the dates and updates if changed but wondering if there is a better more efficient way.

Comment: Hey MadMac. Did you get anywhere with this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you see that, and did it make sense?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I think I will end up taking this approach and write the last refresh date to the user doc every time an update is made.  If the user is reloaded at any point I will check the last refresh date in the doc against the firebase user and update the date in the doc if it is > 12 hours or similar.  Better than a bulk admin process.  I just need to do it in all apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having each client write it themselves when they go online?

It won't be guaranteed (as malicious users may call the API themselves without writing the value), but it will prevent you from having to have an administrative process over a data set that will be hard to predict the growth of.